# When should a ride sharing app calculate the fare?

Tags: android

Should Ride sharing app calculate the fare at the end of the trip or should the app charge the user the estimated fare shown at the beginning of the Trip request?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Kayhan, the question you asked is not related to programming problems rather related to opinions regarding some application features. Please read the guideline to ask questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better performance you should calculate total fare after ride end. At the end of a ride distance and time may change and you should calculate fare after final changes of distance and time.